# Can't update chromedriver in macos10.12.6

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to update chromedriver from 2.30 to 2.35. However, after I `brew install chromedriver`, the default chromedriver is still 2.30. If I redo brew, it will tell me I have already installed 2.35 version, but when I use `chromedriver --version`, it still shows 2.30. Can any one tell me why it's that? And can I know where does this brew install?

Thanks!

Output of `brew list chromedriver`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.35/bin/chromedriver 
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.35/homebrew.mxcl.chromedriv‌​er.plist
```

and output of `which chromedriver` shows it's using version 2.30 in other path.

Comment: What is the output of `brew list chromedriver` and `which chromedriver`? Also, have you tried `brew update` then `brew upgrade`?

Comment: @Raptor, the out put of brew list chromedriver is '/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.35/bin/chromedriver
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.35/homebrew.mxcl.chromedriver.plist'.

     'which chromedriver' showed me another address, which is my old chromedriver 2.30. I tried brew update and brew upgrade, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Raptor May I still ask how to shade the code.. thanks...

Comment: You can't apply formatting in comments. You can only format the codes in the question body. I just helped you put the contents into your questions.

Comment: The question is, how do you install version 2.30? It seems that you're not installing the version via Homebrew.

Comment: Can you try `brew switch chromedriver 2.35`?

Comment: @Raptor I don't quite remember how I install it ... The output of `brew switch chromedriver 2.35`:
    `Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.35`,
    `1 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.35`. And still, after that chromedriver version shows 2.30

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by:

```
brew uninstall chromedriver
```

then I did

```
brew info chromedriver
```

which told me to do:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew cask install chromedriver
```

It installed `chromedriver` 2.40

Answer (score 8):

`brew cask reinstall chromedriver`

In my case helped just reinstalling `chromedriver`

Example output:

```
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.90/chromedriver_mac64.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'chromedriver'.
==> Uninstalling Cask chromedriver
==> Unlinking Binary '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'.
==> Purging files for version 2.45 of Cask chromedriver
==> Installing Cask chromedriver
==> Linking Binary 'chromedriver' to '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'.
  chromedriver was successfully installed!
```

Answer (score 6):

Install or reinstall it using:

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

When you need to update it, use:

```
brew cask upgrade chromedriver
```

For newr versions of MacOs and brew:

```
brew upgrade chromedriver --cask
```

Comment: For newer versions of MacOs and brew:
` brew upgrade chromedriver --cask`

Answer (score 3):

Fileland :perform below steps please

1. Go to usr/local/bin folder if you are admin to your machine
2. Trash the existing chrmodriver exe file
3. Go to terminal and hit the command    brew cask reinstall chromedriver
4. check the version on the same terminal using the command `chromdriver --version`.

Answer (score 2):

The new version of the command to upgrade chromedriver is the following:

```
brew upgrade --cask chromedriver
```

If you receive the error:

> “chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

You need to put it outside the quarantine with:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the 2.35 archive and unzip
2. Place the standalone executable chromedriver wherever you like
3. Add that location to the PATH variable by adding the following line to your .bash_profile file:

   ```
   export PATH="/Users/location/of/chromedriver:$PATH"
   ```

Comment: Thank you, it helps. May I ask whether you know how to remove the old version?

Answer (score 0):

For OSX Catalina 10.15.6:

brew upgrade chromedriver