# Chromedriver can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, macos-big-sur

**Environment:** 
OS : Big Sur 11.1 
Homebrew 3.2.13 
Python 3.9.7

**Command:** 
`chromedriver —version`

**Error GUI Alert:** 
[image]￼

**Error via output of .py file attempt to run chromedriver:** 
`raise WebDriverException(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9`

---

##### Fix Method (1)

As stated in the alert, try updating chromedriver:

*Uninstall the current version:*
`brew uninstall chromedriver`

*Verify that chromedriver is uninstalled:*
`brew info chromedriver`

*Install the newest version of chromedriver:*
`brew install chromedriver`

*You can also try:*
`brew reinstall chromedriver`

##### Fix Method (2) : Still Stuck

If you are still experiencing the issue, this fix helped me.

*Determine which chromedriver is being used, run:*
`which chromedriver`

*Result :*
`/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver`

*Use the path to chromedriver in the following command to unblock it.* 
`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver`

*Now run the following:*
`chromedriver —version`

Result :
`ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63`

Chromedriver should successfully execute.

**Reference** 
[coorasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837638/coorasse)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513369/cant-update-chromedriver-in-macos10-12-6).

Comment: Try answers given here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362018/macos-catalinav-10-15-3-error-chromedriver-cannot-be-opened-because-the-de

Answer (score 14):

For downloading from the chrome drive website
this one worked for me for MAC m1 chip

Use the path to chromedriver in the following command to unblock it.

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine path/to/chromedrive
```

Comment: You can get the path with `which`: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine $(which chromedriver)`

Comment: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine $(which chromedriver)`

Comment: run `chromedriver --version` to verify that it worked

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900371/webdriversnetworkerror-mac64-m1-chromedriver

Comment: @smtlaissezfaire That ^^^ did it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue this morning, this is what fixed it for me.

1. Go to the system and preferences -> security and privacy.
2. Then under general tab you will see a notification that about the
   exec you are trying to open.
3. Just click "open anyway" there.
4. Go back to the chromedriver exe and open it it will then give you the       same error but along with that you will get an option to open it.
5. Click Open and it should resolve.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this thing in tests:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

It installs driver even if you don't have one here:

```
/Users/ME/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac_arm64/112.0.5615/chromedriver
```

But when I used this command to install driver:

```
brew install chromedriver
```

It had been installed here:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver
```

So I've got two chromedrivers on my mac. All that i had to do is manually remove these two and then just launch my tests. It worked